# Could not use v-if with boolean and useState in Nuxtjs3 application

Tags: react-hooks, nuxtjs3, vuetifyjs3

I created a nuxtjs3 application, in a login page i just put a boolean in useState, and reuse the value in component, value seems to be present but if i use is in vuetify object it does not work

here the code where i put the boolean

```
function onSubmit(values: any) {
const {data: token} = useFetch(REST_API_URL + '/auth/signin', {method: "POST", body: values})

watch(token, (newToken) => {

    if(newToken){
        localStorage.setItem('token', newToken)
        useState<boolean>('isConnected', () => true);
        useState('test', ()=>'test');
    }
    console.log('Login')
    console.log(newToken)
},{
    deep: true,
    immediate:true
    }
)
```

i tried also tu put a string value to check if it is working
here the usage of values

```
<template>
<div>
    <v-sheet>
        <v-toolbar elevation="4" class="primary-color">
            <NuxtLink to="/" src>
                <img src="/images/logo.png"/>
            </NuxtLink>

            <v-toolbar-title>{{test}}  {{isConnected}} Application des commandes</v-toolbar-title>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>

            <v-btn v-if="isConnected" v-text="'deconnect'" href="/login"></v-btn>
            <v-btn v-else v-text="'connect'" href="/login"></v-btn>

        </v-toolbar>
    </v-sheet>
</div>
```

```
<script script="ts" setup>

const isConnected = useState('isConnected');
const test  = useState( 'test' );

console.log( 'token' );
console.log( isConnected );


</script>
```

in the menu bar i see "test" and true but the button write connect and should display deconnect

PS in log of isConnected this is what is logged

```
ObjectRefImpl {                                                                                                                                                                 
16:42:59
_object: {},
_key: '$sisConnected',
_defaultValue: undefined,
__v_isRef: true
}
```

I tried with a simple

```
const bool = ref(true);
```

and it is working so i think it is related to the useState and boolean value

I tried to reproduce the project, just delete the vuetity PART and the whatch one (with rest call) it is working... what is wird, the log in menu of the object always display good data, and if i use it in {{}} we saw result...

[image]